# snowfall effect using particle

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to create app using cocos2d. I have created the snowfall effect using particle system but I am unable to hold the snowflakes onto an object.
In short The snowfall should fall onto a person and some of the snowflakes should stay on the head. Also when the iPad you shake iPad the snowflakes should fall down.
Please let me know how to achieve the above? I need to deliver this urgent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, instead of doing it programatically, I would have three different sprite sets for a person:

- Normal sprite set for person.
- Sprite set for person with snow on him.
- Sprite set for person with some less snow and some snow around the body (for shaking on iPad)

Then use them according to situation.

Comment: Good to know. If you like, please share the app store link for your game when you complete it. :)